# Looping Through an Array of Arrays returned by JSON API Call

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, intel-xdk

I am writing an App using Intel XDK, and I am using a Wordpress API to obtain user information. The url produces the following:

```
{"status":"ok","0":{"id":2,"username":"testshop","shopname":"shopname","url":"","displayname":"testshop","nickname":"Test Shop","avatar":"80","longitude":"54.5591894,-1.237610600000039","gender":"Menswear","mensCats":"Tech Geek| Indie Lad| Vintage Gent| Casual Bloke","womensCats":""},"1":{"id":3,"username":"testShop2","shopname":"","url":"","displayname":"testShop2","nickname":"Test Shop 2","avatar":"","longitude":"54.5576249,-1.2475360999999338","gender":"Womenswear","mensCats":"","womensCats":"Indie Babe| Vintage Queen"}}
```

I have another API call, which when called, only returns one array, and I can access this information fine, as I do not have to loop through. However, I am not sure how to loop through the above. Below is the code I use to get the JSON:

```
   $.getJSON(url, function(json){
      var name = json.nickname;
   }
```

Could anyone help with the best way to iterate through the data.

Thank You

Comment: Exactly what do you want to retrieve from your nested object (**not** "array of arrays")?

Answer (score 0):

Since your code doesn't produce an array but an object then you can do something like this:

```
$.getJSON(url, function(json){
      if(json.status === "ok")
      {
          var keys = Object.keys(json).filter(function(str){ return str !== "status" });
          for(var i = 0 ; i < keys.length; i++)
          {
              console.log(json[keys[i]]);
          }
      }
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/cnz4L7jn/).